# How to show live IMA ads on Exoplayer with android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, exoplayer

Hello guys Im implementing exoplayer with IMA ads on my android project

Im using this as a reference https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/android/client-side

the problem is i don't know how to generate my own ad tag with adsense to show live IMA ads can anyone help me with this thank you very much